# How to create an album row layout(in xml)?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'd like to know what would be the best way to structure a row like this in xml:

[image: ListView Row]

There's 2 `ImageViews`(one for the star and one for the cover) and 2 `TextViews` (one for "Album" and one for "Artist"). I'm not sure which kind of layout would be the best and how to structure this row.

Comment: This can be done using LinearLayout.Try it is simple, Otherwise you should post your xml code that you have design for this.

Comment: [See this Example](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-image-listview.html)  and create own row xml file as per your image

Comment: Use Relative Layout for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `RelativeLayout`(there are other options too):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/album_cover"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="the drawable" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/star"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="the drawable" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/star"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/album_cover"
        android:text="Album" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/star"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/album_cover"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
    android:text="Artist" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like that:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="2dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextView"
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextView"
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'll rather use a RelativeLayout.